# How to dynamically place Azure Data flow output in folders named after date

Tags: azure-files, azure-data-factory

I have a dataflow in a pipeline that outputs a json file. Every time it runs I want the json file to be placed in a folder that is name the dynamically the current time stamp down to the second that the folder is pipeline is ran. I have tried put a utcNow function in the file path setup of the output dataset [dataset folderpath setup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRvqY.jpg). But I get a

"Cannot create through WASB that has colons in the name" error.

Even though I have created folders with colons in the name through Azure storage before. Please help.

Comment: You say you have created folders with colons in the name through Azure storage before, can you show us the example?

Comment: Can you show us you whole pipeline overview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested that set folder name with colons and expression in Data Flow.

No matter we set the folder name with colons or expression, We will get the error:

```
{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: JSON parsing error, unsupported encoding or multiline","Details":"at Sink 'sink1': org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted."}
```

[image]

According the error message, folder name with colons and expression function are not supported in Data Flow.

It only works in Copy active sink dataset.